# Method to Check whether the Response is JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, json, response

I need a function to check whether the incomming response is JSON or NOT in PHP

For eg. my JSON is this

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
```

Comment: starting and ending ' removed and it looks like a valid JSON

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this

```
function check_whether_json($response){
    if(json_decode($response) != NULL){
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

and CHECK like this

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
```

Now Checking Starts

```
if(check_whether_json($json)){
// Proceed ur code...
}
```

Comment: [`null` is valid JSON](http://codepad.org/p1690dQg). You could also return the results of that condition, I don't believe you gain anything by repeating the return value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `json_decode()` on it and then check `json_last_error()`. If you have an error, it's not valid JSON.

Keep in mind it's not good enough to just check for `null`. [The string `null` is valid JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526995/is-null-valid-json-4-bytes-nothing-else) (and it decodes as [such](http://codepad.org/crPcB2wx)).

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can validate Like this.

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

    if($json) {
       $ob = json_decode($json);
       if($ob === null) {
           echo 'Invalid Json';
       } else {
          echo 'Valid Json';
       }
    }
```

Comment: `null` is valid JSON, AFAIK.

Comment: json_decode is null then invalid Json

Comment: [Is it?](http://codepad.org/p1690dQg)

Comment: No It is not http://codepad.org/Fq9DCRtq

Comment: That proves nothing. What did you expect the string `null` to deserialize to?

Answer (score -1):

```
$json_request = (json_decode($request) != NULL) ? true : false;
```

Taken from: [PHP check whether Incoming Request is JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377564/php-check-whether-incoming-request-is-json-type)

Does that work?

Comment: You shouldn't just grab an answer from another and post it, even with attribution. It'd be better to close this as a duplicate (or if you can't due to low rep, flag it perhaps).

Comment: Im sorry, just wanted to help, wont do that again

Comment: I'm sure your intentions were good. :)